# hide /show an anchor dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag. I want to hide/show it dynamically. I can't put it inside a div /span for some reason. How can i do it?

Comment: I don't know what a "tap" is in this context. Please rephrase the question and show some code

Comment: You should give a lot more context and maybe some sample code. Nobody knows what you're talking about

Comment: I *think* that is a horrible misspelling of "anchor tag" (not that you can show or hide tags except in source code, only elements).

Comment: Using jQuery you can find the anchor easily by id, class or even its text.

Comment: Hide-:document.getElementById("showLastCommentModalFn").style.cssText="display:none"; Show-:document.getElementById("showLastCommentModalFn").style.cssText="display:block";

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have a reference to the DOM element for the anchor tag, do this:

```
// Hide
element.style.display = "none";

// Show again
element.style.display = "";
```

There are several ways you'd get that reference. For instance, if the anchor has an `id`, you can use `getElementById`:

HTML:

```
<a href='whatever' id='foo'>Whatever</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
element = document.getElementById('foo');
```

If the anchor doesn't have an ID and you don't want to add one for whatever reason, you can use other information about it to identify the correct element. This is most easily done with a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) that will give you the ability to use CSS selectors to find the anchor(s) in question. Without a library, you have to rely on a small number of well-supported DOM functions or deal with browser variations, which is what the libraries help you avoid.

Here's an example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/awino3/3)) of looping through **all** of the anchors on a page and hiding one based on its `href`:

HTML:

```
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a>
<a href='http://superuser.com'>SuperUser</a>
<a href='http://serverfault.com'>ServerFault</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var links, index, link;

links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (index = 0; index < links.length; ++index) {
  link = links[index];
  if (link.href.indexOf('superuser') >= 0) {
    link.style.display = "none";
    break;
  }
}
```

That gets dramatically easier if you use a library. For instance, here's a jQuery version of it ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/awino3/2)):

```
$('a[href*=superuser]').hide();
```

Here's the Prototype version ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/awino3/4)):

```
$$('a[href*=superuser]').invoke('hide');
```

Comment: Hide-:document.getElementById("showLastCommentModalFn").style.cssText="display:none";
Show-:document.getElementById("showLastCommentModalFn").style.cssText="display:block";

Comment: @SandeepJain - Only if you want to wipe out all other inline styles on the element. In general, setting `cssText` is poor practice.